# Plotting greek letters and plain text in ggplot2 graphs via Rpy2

Tags: python, ggplot2, rpy2

How can I make an x or y label like `"$\alpha$ + $\beta$ is my label"` in a ggplot2 plot within Rpy2? I've tried getting any greek letter on the plot using `r.expression`:

```
p = ggplot2.ggplot(mydata) + r.xlab(r.expression("alpha"))
```

but this does not work. How can greek letters get plotted alongside regular text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R's `expression()` is taking objects, calls, or expression and returns an expression (that's a way to manipulate unevaluated code). `expression("alpha")` returns the string `"alpha"` (like it would if writing in R `expression("alpha")`.

One way to get an expression is to parse a string. Using your example in the question that would be:

```
from rpy2.rinterface import parse
p = ggplot2.ggplot(mydata) + scale_x_continuous(parse("alpha"))
```

Should you want to mix expressions (that is syntactically valid R code) with general text (something that cannot be parsed as code, say using spaces and punctuation) you'll have to
use R's `paste()` *in* the code to parse (this might seem esoteric, but that's the way one
has to do it in R as well):

```
p = ggplot2.ggplot(mydata) + \
    ggplot2.scale_x_continuous(parse('paste(alpha, " and ", beta)'))
```

Comment: thanks - but then how do you combine it with non parsed text? If I try `scale_x_continuous(parse("alpha") + " and " + parse("beta"))` I get the error that I am mixing types: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpVector' and 'str'`

Comment: @user248237dfsf - I edited the answer to cover that situation.